# For loop querying in Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this code and my goal is to send message to my recipients like email (Cc) but it doesn't loop, I have 2 recipients but I can only send a message to the first one.

```
DatabaseReference emailReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference(STUDENTS);
DatabaseReference carbonCopyReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference(STUDENTS);
emailReference.keepSynced(true);
carbonCopyReference.keepSynced(true);
List<String> carbonUids = new ArrayList<>();
carbonUids.clear();

for (int i = 0, emailsSize = emails.size(); i < emailsSize; i++) {

    String email = emails.get(i);
    Log.d("interactor--emails", email);
    Query emailQuery = emailReference.orderByChild("email").startAt(email).endAt(email+UF8FF);
    emailQuery.keepSynced(true);

    emailQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                carbonUids.add(snapshot.getKey());
                Log.d("interactor--carbonKey", String.valueOf(carbonUids));
                for (String carbonUid : carbonUids) {

                    carbonCopyReference.child(carbonUid).child(CONSULTATION_REQUESTS).push().setValue(response);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            listener.onFailure(databaseError.getMessage());
        }
    });
    if (i == (emails.size()-1)){
        listener.onSuccess("Request Sent");
        context.startActivity(new Intent(context, ConsultDepartmentsActivity.class));
        ((Activity) context).finish();
        ((Activity) context).overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right);
    }
}
```

2 records in first recipient while no record sent to second. (I still don't have 10 reputation points to post images)

2 records in first recipient -

[image: 2 records in first recipient]

Child with open details such as email, fName are my target recipients

Child with open details (email, fName, lastName) -

[image: Child with open details (email, fName, lastName)]

I saw this code but I don't know how I could do this in Java. Is this possible or doable in Java at least?

```
for (var each = 0; each < alumAroundId.length; each++) { 
console.log("outside of rootRef", each); 
(function(each){ rootRef.child('users').child(alumAroundId[each].key).once('value', function (eventSnap) 
{ 
console.log(each, "inside the rootRef is off"); var thisUser = eventSnap.val(); thisUser.distance = alumAroundId[each].distance; $scope.allAlumAround.push(thisUser); 
}); 
})(each); 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I observed in my list that the 2nd email item have white spaces. I have to add `.trim()` to `email` string variable for the query code read each email inside for loop.

[Finally it worked after adding trim() to email string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ytPS1.png)

Here's the working code

```
for (int i = 0; i < emails.size(); i++) {
 String email = emails.get(i);
 Log.d("interactor--email", email.trim());
 Log.d("interactor--last-emails", String.valueOf(emails).trim());

 queryReference(emailReference, carbonCopyReference, email.trim(), response, listener);
}

private void queryReference( DatabaseReference emailReference, DatabaseReference carbonCopyReference, String email, ConsultationResponse response, SendingMessageListener listener) {
    emailReference.orderByChild("email").equalTo(email).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() { //.startAt(classmateEmails[i]).endAt(classmateEmails[i]+UF8FF)
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
            Log.d("interactor--snapshotKey", dataSnapshot.getKey());
            List<String> carbonUids = new ArrayList<>();
            carbonUids.add(dataSnapshot.getKey());
            Log.d("interactor--emailSnap", email);

            Log.d("interactor--carbonKey1", String.valueOf(carbonUids));
            Log.d("interactor--carbonSize1", String.valueOf(carbonUids.size()));

            for (int i = 0; i < carbonUids.size(); i++) {
                String carbonUid = carbonUids.get(i);
                Log.d("interactor--carbonLoop", carbonUid);
                carbonCopyReference.child(carbonUid).child(CONSULTATION_REQUESTS).push().setValue(response);
                if (i == (carbonUids.size() - 1)) { //i == (emails.size() - 1)
                    Log.d("interactor--finishLoop", "Loop finished.");
                    listener.onSuccess("Request Sent");
                    context.startActivity(new Intent(context, ConsultDepartmentsActivity.class));
                    ((Activity) context).finish();
                    ((Activity) context).overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

}
```

[Data added to recipients. Yaaay! (I don't have 10 reputation points yet, please bear with me)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8RmYq.png)

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is that you are iterating the `carbonUids` list while adding elements to the same list. To solve this, you need to get that for loop out of the other for loop like this:

```
emailQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            carbonUids.add(snapshot.getKey());
            Log.d("interactor--carbonKey", String.valueOf(carbonUids));

        }

        for (String carbonUid : carbonUids) {
            carbonCopyReference.child(carbonUid).child(CONSULTATION_REQUESTS).push().setValue(response);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        listener.onFailure(databaseError.getMessage());
    }
});
```

Comment: I did that kind of loop but what happens next is it sends 2 messages to the first recipient, while the second recipient doesn't received anything.

Comment: There are 2. I don't understand why loop doesn't work after `Log.d("interactor--emails", email);` where it displays in my logcat the 2 email addresses

Comment: Please add a more detailed screenshot of your database.

Comment: Yes. After querying and sending to email 1, I will make query for email 2, get what I need and do something about it. Both will get the message.

Comment: So there is a problem with your for loop. But you can also try to do a reverse look-up and put all the data you need in a node like `uidOne_uidTwo`, if it is possible.

Comment: I have observed that looping is not working when applying to querying. Do you have any idea why?

I tried this but it only executes the 1st item in the list which is email 1
`emailReference.orderByChild("email").equalTo(emails.get(i))`

Comment: So you say that the for loop iterates only once?

Comment: sadly, yes. I reversed and everything but it only works that way

Comment: Have you tried to use only `for (int i = 0; i < emails.size(); i++)`?

Comment: Yes, I did that too, but it does the same.

I saw this code but I don't know how I could do this in Java


`for (var each = 0; each < alumAroundId.length; each++) {
    console.log("outside of rootRef", each);
    (function(each){    
        rootRef.child('users').child(alumAroundId[each].key).once('value', function (eventSnap) {
            console.log(each, "inside the rootRef is off");
            var thisUser = eventSnap.val();
            thisUser.distance = alumAroundId[each].distance;
            $scope.allAlumAround.push(thisUser);
        });
    })(each);
 }`

Comment: Please add to your question not at my answer.

Comment: Aw, sorry about that, I got confused. Please check my updated question.